# Two occurrences of criteria in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query working great and it shows me all agents with records of at least 250000.

How do I further isolate records where agents have at least 2 records >= 250000

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
`RESI`.`ListingAgentFullName`,
`RESI`.`ListingAgentMLSID`,
`RESI`.`ListingAgentNumber`
FROM
`RESI`
WHERE
`RESI`.`SearchPrice` >=  '250000'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ListingAgentFullName, ListingAgentMLSID, ListingAgentNumber
FROM RESI WHERE SearchPrice >= 250000
GROUP BY ListingAgentFullName, ListingAgentMLSID, ListingAgentNumber
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Live example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7acf3/1/0